# how to run 2 webapp application with multiple re-direction in 2 different context with nginx ingress configutation

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, nginx-ingress

In my k8s cluster, I have 2 web application,

1. app1 running in app1-k8s-svc:80
2. app2 running in app2-k8s-svc:9090

which has multiple rediection,

**Note: i dont have any control to change the nginx proxy configuration of both the apps (app1 and app2)**

I have nginx ingress configured for both the apps as below,

### ingress configuration

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url : "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:              
      - path: /app1(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: "app1-k8s-svc"
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /app2(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: "app2-k8s-svc"
            port:
              number: 9090
```

with this configuration, app1 and app2 goes to right service on the first browser call, however on the subsequent url redirection, landing back to locahost not to that respective service, this causes the issue.

from http://localhost/app2 ==> forwards to http://app2-k8s-svc:9090/link1 subsequent redirection falls back to http://localhost/link1 itself which is wrong. It should fall back like http://localhost/app2/link1.

looks like I am missing some basics. could someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the applications are not aware of the path prefixes `/app1/` and `/app2/`.

You need to pass the full paths including the prefixes to the respective applications by forgoing the `rewrite-target` annotation in the ingress. Of course you need to ensure both applications can handle the prefixes accordingly.

Comment: Hi Lukman, I did try that, by creating 2 ingresses and adding the full path in rewrite-target. still the same, not much improvement like "rewrite-target: /app1/$2"

Answer (score 0):

As far I found, ingress is just meant for routing, from URL prefix to the specific k8s service, if we have multiple re-direction, then it needs to be fixed at the application level.

in my case apps are Prometheus and OpenSearch-Dashboard, both of them support adding a baseURL or basepath, so that context is set for each app, and then on re-direction works fine.

Sample from OpenSearch-dashboard,

```
          env:
        - name: server.ssl.enabled
          value: "false"
        - name: OPENSEARCH_HOSTS
          value: http://opensearch-service:9200
        - name: SERVER_BASEPATH
          value: /osd
        - name: SERVER_REWRITEBASEPATH
          value: "true"
```